# Different versions between a nuget package and its referenced nuget packages

Tags: c#, .net-core, nuget, azure-functions

I have an Azure Function (version 3, dotnet 3.1) referencing the following nuget package:

> Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration

When I try to install this nuget, I get the version 5.x of the package, which causes the installation of

> Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions

But I have conflicts when running my function.  The solution found on several other topics, is to downgrade the nuget package, as the Azure Function doesn't support 5.0 dependency for the Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions package.

So I execute the following command line in the package manager console to install the initial nuget package:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration -Version 3.1.14 -DependencyVersion Lowest
```

But it always install the version 5.x of the dependency "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions"

Any advice to download the right version of the dependency?

Comment: Specify the version in the .proj file. After that, the wrong package should not be installed

Comment: I used the command you gave, [everything](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwbAc.png) seems to be no problem.

Comment: Please share all your installed nuget packages with us. Did you install any other nuget packages that has dependency with `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions 5.x`? Please check it. And in my side, [it shows the right version 3.1.14](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QnQ0B.png). Also, please close VS, delete all files under `C:\Users\xxx\.nuget\packages`, then restart your project to check again.

Comment: I found my problem which was not related to the azure function. But from other projects in my dependencies.  I did a wide downgrade to  3.1.14 (even project with net5) and everything is fixed.  Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the command you gave, everything seems to be no problem:

[image]

**1.** As `Sara Liu-MSFT` mentioned in the comments, you may need to check whether other assemblies reference `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions`. If so, you may need to downgrade that assembly.

You can check here:

[image]

**2.** Or you can try to manually reference the `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions` assembly:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions" Version="3.1.14" />
```

[image]

Comment: As mentioned above, doing a full downgrade of all my projects in my solution fixed the problem.  But you are right in your remarks (as I did the same).  So I will mark your answer as solution.  Thank you very much!